# What's the best way to copy/fill a large array with a smaller array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-2.0

I have a large int[] array and a much smaller int[] array.  I want to fill up the large array with values from the small array, by repeat copying the small array into the large array until it is full (so that large[0] = large[13] = large[26] ... = small[0] etc.).  I already have a simple method:

```
int iSource = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < destArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (iSource >= sourceArray.Length)
    {
        iSource = 0; // reset if at end of source
    }
    destArray[i] = sourceArray[iSource++];
}
```

But I need something more elegant, and hopefully faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the winning answer is the slowest with the provided source array!

The solution I was going to propose was

```
for (int i = 0; i < destArray.Length; i++)
{
    destArray[i] = sourceArray[i%sourceArray.Length];
}
```

but when i tested the perf over 100000 iterations using the inputs in the answering question it performed worse than the questioners loop.

here is the output from my little test app

```
array copy 164ms      (Nelson LaQuet's code) 
assign copy 77ms      (MusiGenesis code)
assign mod copy 161ms (headsling's code)
```

Comment: Are you saying my original code was the fastest? (I never benchmarked any of these)

Comment: yes! assign copy (yours) scored 77ms for 1 million iterations. not bad eh?

Answer (score 2):

Have your loop work using the `Array.Copy()` overload that lets you copy from one array into the a particular index in the destination array.

```
if (sourceArray.Length == 0) return; // don't get caught in infinite loop

int idx = 0;

while ((idx + sourceArray.Length) < destArray.Length) {
    Array.Copy( sourceArray, 0, destArray, idx, sourceArray.Length);

    idx += sourceArray.Length;
}

Array.Copy( sourceArray, 0, destArray, idx, destArray.Length - idx);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Temp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
            int[] array2 = new int[213];

            for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i += array.Length)
            {
                int length = array.Length;
                if ((i + array.Length) >= array2.Length)
                    length = array2.Length - i;
                Array.Copy(array, 0, array2, i, length);
            }

            int count = 0;
            foreach (int i in array2)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString() + " " + (count++).ToString() + "\n");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

:)

*EDIT*
Found bug where if they were not dividable by each other it would crash. Fixed now :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, `i % array.Length` will never be anything other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;source.Length!= 0 && source.Length!= i;i++)
        {
            destination[i] = source[i];
        }
```

i got this from my old project and modified it. u may want to change a thing or two typos in it given there might be typos in it